# Recovering only deleted partition(not formatted nor overwritten)

Tags: data-recovery, partition-recovery, hard-drive-recovery, file-recovery, recovery-partition

I have an external hard disk and by mistake I only removed its partition. But after that I understood my mistake and stop doing anything on that. I ejected it immediately.
It has 1TB capacity. It is Western Digital my passport.
I want to know, is there any possibility to recover everything with folders as it is not overwritten?
What is the best way of recovering for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of partition recovery tools out there, some of them even let you use the whole thing for free.

Minitool Patition Recovery and Acronis Recovery Expert Wizard

are two good ones that'll let you do it, preferably run them from a different hard drive or from a usb

Minitool : https://www.minitool.com/free-tools/minitool-partitionrecovery.html
Acronis Recovery : https://www.acronis.com/en-eu/articles/partition-recovery/

Comment: I used those two previously. I don't remember, is there any possibility to recover with file hierarchy?

Comment: If you recover the partition itself, the file index will be intact, if you recover files directly then you'll have to manage them manually.